# How to change javascript slider options on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'd like to set "automatic" to false when a user clicks on a sliders marker, here's what the code looks like:

```
$('#imageslider').bjqs({
  animtype      : 'fade',
    height        : 698,
    width         : 1920,
    responsive    : true,
    automatic           : <?= $manualAdvancing ?>,
    showcontrols    : false,
    animduration    : 450, // how fast the animation are
        animspeed       : <?= $delay ?>,
});


$('.bjqs-markers li').click(function() {

});
```

and so when `.click` gets performed, `automatic` in `#imageslider.bjqs` options should set to false, how can I do that?

Comment: i have check for http://www.basic-slider.com/, its not provide any method to set settings, even not provide to remove slider, so prefer to use other jQuery Slider

Answer (score 0):

Access the slider by its ID, and try changing its "automatic" value.

```
$('.bjqs-markers li').click(function() {
  var $slider = $("#imageslider");
  $slider.bjqs("automatic", false);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried:

```
var aut = <?= $manualAdvancing ?>;
$('#imageslider').bjqs({
  animtype      : 'fade',
  height        : 698,
  width         : 1920,
  responsive    : true,
  automatic           : aut,
  showcontrols    : false,
  animduration    : 450, // how fast the animation are
  animspeed       : <?= $delay ?>,
});


$('.bjqs-markers li').click(function() {
 aut=false;
});
```